# How can I rephrase this sentence in a more eloquent way?

Tags: word-choice

This is the sentence right now:

> My nights’ dreams of majestic quests to explore its outskirts on the back of my magnificent horse extended into the light of day

If it's not clear, I'm basically trying to say that at night I dream about going on quest to explore my imaginary world while on a horse and that those dreams extend into the day (through day dreams). It just sounds really clunky and not very clear right now. How would you suggest I rephrase it?

Comment: I actually like it. Could these things be a matter of taste? You feel it is 'clunky'; it is, but it is clunky because it has a rhythm, and you are riding a horse! (Will the hoofs be making a clunky sound?) 'its' - do you wish to elaborate: the outskirts of what you are exploring? 'Your nights' dreams' have started to become longer and now extend into the light of day, or do u mean to refer to a particular dream that extended into the day? (Apologies, if I am rushing the story - I think it is really interesting...)

Comment: This forum isn't really supposed to give writing advice.

Comment: You've already got 2 versions: a poetic version (quoted) and a prosaic version (beneath the quote). What are you looking for in the third or subsequent versions?

Comment: This is entirely opinion-based, but I think it should be broken into two sentences, along with other changes: *I had been having nightly dreams of majestic quests in which I explored an imaginary world on the back of a magnificent horse. After a while, they took the form of daydreams, extending into my waking hours.* The word changes are completely optional, in particular because they change the meaning somewhat, but I think there's more objective stylistic reason to turn the single sentence into two sentences; it aids in the easy parsing of information.

Comment: Is there context to establish what "its" refers to? Other than that, it seems fine if you want flowery language, which seems appropriate when describing dreams.